# Why getting incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression?

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

I'm getting the error regarding lamda expression i don't know why it is doing as so.. Below is my complete class and after that this where i'm getting errors:

This is the full method in case someone would need additional info, basically what this function will do is just allow me to drag the cells in the javafx tableview

```
    private void setCellFactoryForColumns(TableColumn<scheduling, String> col)
{

    col.setCellFactory((TableColumn<scheduling, String> e) -> {
        TableCell<scheduling, String> cell = new TableCell<scheduling, String>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item);
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        };

        col.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<scheduling, String> t) -> {
            ((scheduling)t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setZone1(t.getNewValue());
        });

        cell.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> {
            Dragboard db = cell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString(cell.getText());
            db.setContent(content);
            cell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;"
                        + "-fx-text-fill: white;");
            cell.startEdit();
            cell.setText("Dragged");

            event.consume();
        });

        cell.setOnDragOver((DragEvent event) ->{
            if(event.getGestureSource() != cell &&
                    event.getDragboard().hasString())
            {
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                cell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;"
                        + "-fx-text-fill: white;");
            }
            event.consume();
        });

        cell.setOnDragEntered((DragEvent event) ->{
           if(event.getGestureSource() != cell &&
                   event.getDragboard().hasString()){
               cell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
           } 
           event.consume();
        });

        cell.setOnDragExited((DragEvent event) -> {
           cell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey;");
           event.consume();
        });

        cell.setOnDragDropped((DragEvent event) -> {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;
            if(db.hasString())
            {
                holdData = cell.getText();
                cell.setText(db.getString());
                success = true;
            }

            event.setDropCompleted(success);
            event.consume();
        });

        cell.setOnDragDone((DragEvent event) ->{
           if(event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.MOVE)
           {
               cell.setText(holdData);
           }
           event.consume();
        });
        return cell;
    });
}

}
```

and here is the code which is faulty, it is in  **setCellFactoryForColumns()**

```
        col.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<scheduling, String> t) -> {
        ((scheduling)t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                ).setZone1(t.getNewValue());
    });
```

Comment: And what is the error message..?

Comment: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression?

Comment: @lexicore i know there is to much code thats why i seperated the code, the above is the full method and below it it is the part on my code which is underlined in red in my IDE(the ones which is giving me errors)

Comment: I'd approach this by assigning all intermediate results to local variables with specified types. At one point you'll find out an assignment that does not work. I can't spot it from the code, though.

Comment: which of `CellEditEvent` are you using? did you apply a static import for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lucky guess, since you don't post the whole class, but given that I get the same error, here it is my possible solution on how to fix it:

I've pasted your code as is on my IDE (NetBeans), and then used `Fix Imports`, created the `scheduling` class (by the way, you should use Java naming conventions), and I could reproduce your error:

[image: error]

Then, looking at the imports, I realized that there was something out of place:

```
 import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn.CellEditEvent;
```

Having a look at how the imports were fixed, doing scrolling I found the culprit:

[image: imports]

Obviously this is not correct, as you have a `TableColumn`, so just by fixing it:

```
 import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
```

the error was solved.

So you have to review your imports and make sure you have the right ones.